# How to Move a whole partition to another tabel on another database?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle12c

Database: Oracle 12c

I want to take single partition, or a set of partitions, disconnect it from a Table, or set of tables on DB1 and move it to another table on another database. I would like to avoid doing DML to do this for performance reasons (It needs to be fast).

Each Partition will contain between three and four hundred million records.
Each Partition will be broken up into approximately 300 Sub-Partitions.

The task will need to be automated.

**Some thoughts I had:**

- Somehow put each partition in it's own datafile upon creation, then detaching from the source and attaching it to the destination?
- Extract the whole partition (not record-by-record)
- Any other ***non-DML*** Solutions are also welcom

Example (Move Part#33 from both to DB#2, preferably with a single, operation):

```
 __________________              __________________
| DB#1             |            | DB#2             |
|------------------|            |------------------|
|Table1            |            |Table1            |
|   Part#1         |            |   Part#1         |
|   ...            |            |   ...            |
|   Part#33        |    ---->   |   Part#32        |
|      Subpart#1   |            |                  |
|      ...         |            |                  |
|      Subpart#300 |            |                  |
|------------------|            |------------------|
|Table2            |            |Table2            |
|   Part#1         |            |   Part#1         |
|   ...            |            |   ...            |
|   Part#33        |    ---->   |   Part#32        |
|      Subpart#1   |            |                  |
|      ...         |            |                  |
|      Subpart#300 |            |                  |
|__________________|            |__________________|
```

Comment: You can swap (EXCHANGE) table partitions with tables, and at the same move them to a transportable tablespace, mapped to a particular datafile(s).

Answer (score 1):

Please read the document below with all the examples of exchanging partitions of table.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition